# How do you test hypothesis if you don't do model reduction?

Tags: anova, modeling

Say I fit the model

```
lm(y ~ factor + x)
```

Now, what I used to do is, I would look at p-values to see whether some parameters were close to zero and/or insignificant. I would then say **"hmmm .... maybe those parameters are equal to zero? Let us test this**". Then I would fit another model where that parameter actually is zero, and then I would either use anova F-test or AIC to compare. If the hypothesis is accepted, I would proceed with the new model. Then I would again look at p-values, say "hmmmm..." and repeat.

However, I have been suggested to **not** reduce my initial model, unless it is overly complicated. This is also what the book "regression modelling strategies" tells me.

If so, how do I perform the hypothesis tests like above??? I always do that, and now I don't know what to do.

Comment: This is not the way to do it. There are stepwise selection procedures that are used to decide on a final model.  There are various criteria that are used including adjusted R square and AIC to name a couple of ways.

Comment: Yes, that is what I just told you I do. stepwise selection.

Comment: I am talking abot conventional methods and not the approach you propose.

Comment: The only difference seems to be is that my method is smarter. Instead of removing each and every one variable and comparison with AIC, I am smart enough to only check those with high p-values. It's more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see how the question of evaluating the statistical significance of some model terms has to do with removing them from the model - except in so far, as one way of constructing a likelihood ratio test is to compare nested models with and without a variable. You can in any case get tests for the significance of a variable from the full model from (almost) any statistical software, so you do not normally need to do this yourself.

Additionally, what is problematic about the practice you describe is that this model building does actually invalidate the p-values you look at (unless you do some extra steps to avoid this such as bootstrapping the whole processes etc.). Doing an analysis as if your final model had been the original single pre-specified model is completely inappropriate. Trying to publish such analyses will typically get you rejected at better journals and concealing that this was done would be considered research misconduct.

Also, remember, a failure to reject the null hypothesis that a parameter is zero is not necessarily much of an evidence that the variable truly does not matter. In fact, a variable may be part of a group of absolutely crucial confounders one should adjust for, but for which individually there is not enough power to see that each one matters due to the sample size in the specific dataset.

Furthermore, this approach seems to involve many tests, where some variables are declared significant or not. Of course, that problem does necessarily go away when one looks at just a single model. Presumably, you have some pre-existing hypothesis for why you are looking into the data? What is usually consider good practice is to only do a single hypothesis test to address you one (ideally pre-specified) research hypothesis. All other variables are only there to reduce variability or to adjust for known important confounders/influence factors/etc. (depending on what kind of data we are talking about) and hypothesis testing should have nothing to do with whether they are there or not.